# Passing an internal static class in JLink?

Tags: java

I am trying to get started with the [Stanford NER tools](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) tools in Mathematica, and am having difficulty translating the demo they provide into JLink. The relevant code in the demo is:

```
/* Usage: java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:." NERDemo */

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;

...

 for (CoreLabel word : sentence) { 
 ... w.word() ... word.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class) ...
```

So I tried:

```
InstallJava[ClassPath -> ".../stanford-ner.jar"];

answerAnnotation = LoadJavaClass["edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation"]
```

> JavaClass[edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation,<>]

```
(...things that appear to be working correctly...)

w
```

> « JavaObject[edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel]»

```
w@word[] (* works *)
w@get[answerAnnotation] (* $Failed *)
```

> Java::argx1: Method named get defined in class edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The argument was JavaClass[edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation,<>].

The (inherited) method signature of `get` is

```
get(java.lang.Class<? extends TypesafeMap.Key<VALUE>> key)
```

[http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/ArrayCoreMap.html#get(java.lang.Class)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/util/ArrayCoreMap.html#get%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Try instead passing into `w@get` the following: `JavaNew["edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation"]@getClass[]` (untested).

Comment: cha $ ching. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Java class object can be recovered using the [JLink class loader](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica.html#2306), e.g.:

```
LoadJavaClass["com.wolfram.jlink.JLinkClassLoader"];
answerAnnotation =
  JLinkClassLoader`classFromName @ "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation"
```

This is necessary because the objects returned by `LoadJavaClass` are symbolic proxies, not the actual Java class objects themselves.

Here is a complete example loosely following `NERDemo.java`:

```
$root = "/some/path/to/stanford-ner-distro";
$jar = FileNameJoin @ {$root, "stanford-ner.jar"};
$crf = FileNameJoin @ {$root, "classifiers", "english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz"};

Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[ClassPath -> $jar, JVMArguments -> "-Xmx8g"];

LoadJavaClass["edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier"];
LoadJavaClass["com.wolfram.jlink.JLinkClassLoader"];

$classifier = CRFClassifier`getClassifierNoExceptions @ $crf;
$annotation = JLinkClassLoader`classFromName @
                "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation";

JavaBlock @ Module[{labels}
, labels = JavaObjectToExpression /@ JavaObjectToExpression @ $classifier @ classify @
             "Prophecy tells us more about the prophet than about the world."
; Map[{# @ toString[], # @ get @ $annotation}&, labels, {2}]
]

(*
{{{Prophecy,O},{tells,O},{us,O},{more,O},{about,O},{the,O},
  {prophet,O},{than,O},{about,O},{the,O},{world,O},{.,O}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Leonid Shifrin's answer does the trick: `JavaNew["edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$AnswerAnnotation"]@getClass[]`.